# remove a defined number of messages from a message queue

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

Rather than using `.Purge()`, is there a way to delete a defined number of messages from a queue?

I've tried setting up a `MessageEnumerator` and using `.RemoveCurrrent` after I've done whatever I need to do with the current message but it does not seem to work.

Thanks

```
public Message[] Get10(MessageQueue q)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        int mCount = 0;
        List<Message> ml = new List<Message>();
        try
        {
            MessageEnumerator me = q.GetMessageEnumerator2();
            while (me.MoveNext())
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter > 10)
            {
                mCount = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                mCount = counter;
            }
            counter = 0;
            me.Reset();
            do
            {
                me.MoveNext();
                counter++;
                ml.Add(me.Current);
                me.RemoveCurrent();
            } while (counter < mCount);

        }

        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        }
        Message[] m = ml.ToArray();
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `RemoveCurrent()`, the enumerator is moved to the next message. You do not have to call `MoveNext()` after calling `RemoveCurrent()`.

Another approach you may try is something like the following:

```
    List<Message> ml = new List<Message>();
    int count = 0;

    while(  count < 10 ) {
        ml.Add(me.RemoveCurrent());
        ++count;
    }
```

In this case, you must be aware that `RemoveCurrent` will wait forever if there are no messages left in the queue. If that is not what you want, you may want to use the `RemoveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout)` overload and catch the `MessageQueueException` that get thrown in case of timeout. The `MessageQueueException` class has a `MessageQueueErrorCode` property that is set to `MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout` if a timeout has expired.

Or also (this will get *at most* 10 messages: the loop will exit if the message count in your queue drops to zero):

```
    List<Message> ml = new List<Message>();
    int count = 0;

    while( me.MoveNext() && count < 10 ) {
        ml.Add(queue.ReceiveById(me.Current.Id));
        ++count;
    }
```

Comment: @Theresa Good. Keep in mind that loop will exit in there are less than 10 messages in you queue -- basically, you are dequeuing *at most* 10 messages. If you want to wait until at least 10 messages are in the queue, you should look at the first snippet.